# How to organize imports in a Python class?

Tags: python, class, import

Suppose I have a Python class ABC; I want to import some non-default modules into my project, but I'm not sure if the user who runs my code has them installed. To check, I've enclosed my imports in the class inside a try and catch block, as such:

```
class ABC:
    _canRun = True
    try:
        import XYZ
    except Exception:
        _canRun = False


    def test_function(self):
        if self._canRun:
            import XYZ
            #do stuff using XYZ module
        else:
            print("Cannot do stuff")
            return None
```

I feel like this is bad design for some reason. Is there a better pattern I can use?

Answer (score 1):

imports are usually placed at the start of the py file:

```
try:
    import XYZ
except ImportError:
    XYZ = None

class ABC:
    def test_function(self):
        if XYZ is None:
            raise Exception("Cannot do stuff")
```

However the try/except ImportError trick is usually done when you can pick an alternative:

```
try:
    import XYZ
except ImportError:
    import ZZTop as XYZ # if ZZTop fails, all fails. And that's fine.

class ABC:
    def test_function(self):
        XYZ.something()
```

Otherwise it is advisable to just fail as easly as possible:

```
import XYZ

class ABC:
    def test_function(self):
        XYZ.something()
```

Comment: Okay, so the other classes instansizing class ABC should place a try and catch around the object creation?

Comment: That depends on what you need. In general it is good to fail as early as possible, meaning that if your program depends on a library for its correct functioning then you just do the import without the try except.